# How to check if a String can be made out of specified list of Chars?

Tags: kotlin

I've been trying to create a method that will return true if chars can be used to create a word.
For example, `listOf('a', 'b', 'o'), "baobab") -> true`, and it works fine, but with input: `listOf('a, 'a', "aa")` it returns false instead of true. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

```kotlin
fun canBuildFrom(chars: List<Char>, word: String): Boolean {
    var i = 0
    for (item in chars) {
        for (char in word) {
            if (char.toLowerCase() == item.toLowerCase()) {
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    return (i == word.length)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```kotlin
fun canBuildFrom(chars: List<Char>, word: String) = word.all { char -> char in chars}
```

If you want it to be case insensitive:

```kotlin
fun canBuildFrom(chars: List<Char>, word: String) = chars.map(Char::toLowerCase).let { lowerCasedChars ->
    word.all { char ->
        char.toLowerCase() in lowerCasedChars
    }
}
```

The function can be improved by making it an extension of `String`, and accepting broader interfaces that has `contains`. i.e. `String.canBuildFrom(chars:Collection<Char>)`

Why your code didn't work: Your function accepts a list of Chars as an input. For **every** characters in the string, `i` is increased by **the number of times the character appears in the list**.

Here's some inputs that it might get wrong:

```kotlin
listOf('a', 'a', 'a'), "abb" -> true // should be false
listOf('a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), "abcbcbacbc" -> false // should be true
```

Comment: thank you for a good explanation, but now the tests do not pass because of UpperCase in one of them: listOf('O'), "O") returns false. I've tryed to add .toLowerCase(), but it didn't work out